# ESB Mule 3.7.0 SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake at

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, mule, esb

I am running ESB Mule 3.7.0 when I send a request from client to ESB I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2015-12-21 18:15:24,859 [[my-project].http.request.dispatch.443.41] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Remote host closed connection during handshake javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:953) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:889) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78) ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106) ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]
        at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readLine(HttpServerConnection.java:245) ~[mule-transport-http-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.getRequestLine(HttpServerConnection.java:557) ~[mule-transport-http-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at org.mule.transport.http.HttpRequestDispatcherWork.run(HttpRequestDispatcherWork.java:67) ~[mule-transport-http-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_80] Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
        ... 13 more
```

My https **connecter** is configured as follows:

```
<https:connector name="httpsConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS" clientSoTimeout="10000" cookieSpec="netscape" receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0" sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" validateConnections="true">
        <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="${connector.https.maxThreadsActive}" />
        <https:tls-key-store path="${tls.keystore.location}" keyPassword="${tls.keystore.password}" storePassword="${tls.keystore.password}"/>
        <https:tls-server path="${tls.keystore.location}" storePassword="${tls.keystore.password}"/>
</https:connector>
```

and **https:inbound-endpoint** is defined as:

```
<https:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${httpInbound.secure.host}" port="${httpInbound.secure.port}" doc:name="HTTPS Service" path="${httpInbound.contextRoot}/${external.serviceName}" responseTimeout="${service.timeout}" connector-ref="httpsConnector">
          <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
          <mule-ss:authorization-filter requiredAuthorities="PUBLIC" />
</https:inbound-endpoint>
```

Why do I receive a `SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection` during handshake? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

check your certificate information inside https connector configuration i have used the following stepes and its work properly

```
  <http:request-config name="SharedHttpsRequestConfig" protocol="HTTPS">
     <tls:context>
        <tls:trust-store path="${tls.trust.store}" password="${tls.trust.store.password}"/>
        <tls:key-store path="${tls.trust.store}"  password="${tls.trust.store.password}" keyPassword="${tls.trust.store.key.password}"/>
    </tls:context>  
</http:request-config>
```

and then i have used the above https connector in my flow to call the https service

```
    <http:request config-ref="SharedHttpsRequestConfig"
                   port="${https.port}" host="#[MYMAP.get('DOMAINS')]"
                    path="/api/${version}/${.url}"
                    parseResponse="false"   responseTimeout="${es.mule.http.timeout}"
                method="POST" doc:name="Service">
```

Answer (score 0):

The remote hosts probably did not like what you have sent to it and thus the initial TLS handshake failed. There might be lots of reasons for this, like:

- you don't connect to an SSL service
- the server requires a TLS version not supported by you
- the server requires ciphers not supported by you
- the server requires SNI which you maybe don't use

I don't think it is possible to extract the exact reason based on the information you provide. But, since the server closes the connection I would recommend to look at the server side for errors (log file etc). You might also try with other clients to connect to the server to see if the problem is related to your client configuration or more to the server configuration.